# monty pop opcode in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, free

I did all I could, debugged for over 24hrs, and still could not fix this bug.
I am trying to implement the pop opcode of a monty intepreter.

Testing with test.m file:

```
push 1
push 2
push 3
pall
pop
pall
pop
pall
pop
pall
```

this is what I get as my output when I test my implementation:

```
3
2
1
0
1
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Instead of this:

```
3
2
1
2
1
1
```

pop opcode implementation:

```
#include "monty.h"

/**
 * pop - removes the top element of the stack
 * @stack: the stack
 * @line_number: current line number of the bytecode file
 *
 * Return: Nothing
 */

void pop(stack_t **stack, unsigned int line_number)
{
    stack_t *temp = NULL;

    if (*stack == NULL)
    {
        dprintf(2, "L%d: can't pop an empty stack\n", line_number);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    temp = *stack;
    *stack = (*stack)->prev;

    temp->prev = NULL;
    free(temp);

    if (*stack)
        (*stack)->next = NULL;
}
```

Project repo: https://github.com/scisamir/monty/

Comment: The (/a?) mistake is in `fail_check = check_opcode(words[0], lineno, top);` outside the code you are showing. (you want it to be able to change the `top` pointer, so don't pass it by value, use a double pointer as for `push`)

Comment: Your question should not depend on external links to make sense. See also [mre].